# How to render two const components in a conditional case in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have declared 2 constant components in my React functional component.
I am trying to render them based on a condition,

```
      <Flex.Box w="90px" ml={1}>
        { mycondition
          ? ({ staticButton })
          : ((
            { staticButton })({ conditionalButton }))}
      </Flex.Box>
```

I am trying to render based on if mycondition is true or false. But, I am getting the below error in the console.

```
TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a function
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you share a little more of your code? What is `mycondition` and what are `staticButton` and `conditionalButton`? There's something odd happening with the syntax, but it's too hard to tell the actual issue without seeing more.

Comment: Even if you got this to work strict mode would still throw an error. You probably shouldn't create components inside other components. You should import them and use them normally. It creates neater code, and folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to render 2 components at the same time in a ternary, you should wrap them inside a fragment (<>{staticButton} {conditionalButton}<>). I guess your 2 const are components pass by props ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can move the `staticButton` out of condition:

```
<Flex.Box w="90px" ml={1}>
  {staticButton}
  {mycondition ? conditionalButton : null}
</Flex.Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you're asking here.

1. If you're creating components inside another component you still have to use Pascal Case.
2. You still need to wrap the component name in `< />`. You can't just return a function.
3. Adjacent components need to be in a container.

```js
function Example() {

  const condition = false;

  const StaticButton = () => <div>Static</div>;
  const ConditionalButton = () => <div>Conditional</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {condition
        ? <StaticButton />
        : (<div>
            <StaticButton />
            <ConditionalButton />
          </div>)
       }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```